# Is this valid JPA/Hibernate mapping?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Today I discovered something strange. If I run this code with `-ea` flag. It will fail. Is there anything wrong? This is working fine without `-ea`. But the test environment requires `-ea` flag.

This is the exception I get when run with `-ea` flag:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.hasIdClassOrEmbeddedId(InheritanceState.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2262) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.fillComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:2825) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindIdClass(AnnotationBinder.java:2928) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.mapAsIdClass(AnnotationBinder.java:1066) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:792) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
```

This is minimal trimmed down spring-boot app:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoHibernateTestApplication {

    @Entity
    public static class Product {

        @Id
        private Long id;

    }

    @MappedSuperclass
    public static abstract class ProductOrder {

        @Id
        private Long id;

    }

    @Entity
    public static class ProductOrderSummary extends ProductOrder {
    }

    @Entity
    @IdClass(ProductOrderItem.PK.class)
    public static class ProductOrderItem {

        @Id
        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ProductOrderSummary.class)
        private ProductOrder order;

        @Id
        @ManyToOne
        private Product product;

        public static class PK implements Serializable {
            private Long order;
            private Long product;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoHibernateTestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Environment:
Java17 x86, Linux, Hibernate-Core 5.6.1

Comment: Hmmm. Do your actual classes have getters and setters?

Comment: @crizzis Of course, they have. But irrelevant.